# When is the mysql performance schema event "wait/synch/cond/sql/MYSQL_BIN_LOG::COND_done" fired?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am using Aurora Mysql 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2 and am facing bottlenecks on load testing with a write-heavy workload. On enabling performance insights I noticed that a large number of sessions were waiting on the event **wait/synch/cond/sql/MYSQL_BIN_LOG::COND_done**.

After going through the AWS [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-mysql-synch-wait-events/), I figured that this is caused by large number of commits which is the case in my codebase but the explanation is generic in nature for all the **wait/synch/*/sql/MYSQL_BIN_LOG** events and nowhere in Mysql's or Aurora's documentation I could find the exact situation in which the particular **COND_DONE** event is fired.

Comment: my database also having long wait time due to wait/synch/cond/sql/MYSQL_BIN_LOG::COND_done . Any suggestions what can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what it says in the docs - this is a relatively new section all about tuning with wait events:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Reference.Waitevents.html

"synch/cond/sql/MYSQL_BIN_LOG::COND_done -
You have turned on binary logging. There might be a high commit throughput, large number transactions committing, or replicas reading binlogs. Consider using multirow statements or bundling statements into one transaction. In Aurora, use global databases instead of binary log replication, or use the aurora_binlog_* parameters."

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Max is correct. For my use case, I was not using binlog for replication but for Change Data Capture and there was no way to turn it off in production.

Upgrading Aurora MySQL to 2.10 solved this issue for us due to the introduction of the binlog I/O cache.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/introducing-binlog-i-o-cache-in-amazon-aurora-mysql-to-improve-binlog-performance/

> The binlog I/O cache minimizes read I/O from the Aurora storage engine by keeping the most recent binlog events in its circular cache.

I have detailed the entire process of debugging and fixing this here.
https://blog.hotstar.com/de-bottlenecking-aurora-mysql-for-19-million-concurrent-users-ee98d6247cfe